# Same code works differently in R and R studio

Tags: r, r-grid

While I learned how to plot using grid, R studio showed the result differnet from an example in book. So I run the same code in R, and got the same result to an example in book. I don't know this reason...

below is code.

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5, 4, 2, 2)))
pushViewport(dataViewport(pressure$temperature,pressure$pressure,name="plotRegion"))
grid.points(pressure$temperature, pressure$pressure,name="dataSymbols")
grid.rect()
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()
grid.text("temperature", y=unit(-3, "lines"))
grid.text("pressure", x=unit(-3, "lines"), rot=90)
grid.edit("dataSymbols", pch=2)
upViewport(2)
grid.rect(gp=gpar(lty="dashed"))
downViewport("plotRegion")
grid.text("Pressure (mm Hg)\nversus\nTemperature (Celsius)",x=unit(150, "native"), y=unit(600, "native"))
```

R studio

[image]

R

[image]

Comment: Try to output to a file?

Comment: Can you also share some data so we can reproduce this?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It is fully reproducible. `pressure` is in the datasets package.

Answer (score 3):

This code uses the defaults defined in `gpar`. The help says:

> The default parameter settings are defined by the ROOT viewport, which
>   takes its settings from the graphics device. These defaults may differ
>   between devices (e.g., the default fill setting is different for a PNG
>   device compared to a PDF device).

With RStudio:

```
get.gpar()$fill
#[1] "white"
```

With RGui:

```
get.gpar()$fill
#[1] "transparent"
```

Thus, the RStudio device has different settings. You need to specify explicitly that you don't want the rectangles to be filled.

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5, 4, 2, 2)))
pushViewport(dataViewport(pressure$temperature,pressure$pressure,name="plotRegion"))
grid.points(pressure$temperature, pressure$pressure,name="dataSymbols")
grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = NA))
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()
grid.text("temperature", y=unit(-3, "lines"))
grid.text("pressure", x=unit(-3, "lines"), rot=90)
grid.edit("dataSymbols", pch=2)
upViewport(2)
grid.rect(gp=gpar(lty="dashed", fill = NA))
downViewport("plotRegion")
grid.text("Pressure (mm Hg)\nversus\nTemperature (Celsius)",x=unit(150, "native"), y=unit(600, "native"))
```

[image: resulting plot]